# What is the easiest way to highlight/emphasize duplicate records of a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, reportbuilder3.0

I have a query that returns a ton of columns, but for one particular column (lp_num = pallet identifier) there is a duplicate value. It's totally ok because another 2 fields in the same record have a different value. In summary:

**Query**

```
t.lp_num     t.lot     t.qty
A            lot_1     -141
A            lot_2     -94
B            lot_1     -235
C            lot_1     -235
```

On the report, I need to show that `t.lp_num = A` has 2 rows instead of the standard 1 row. At first I tried using some sort of conditional formatting in the expression for the textbox color but I couldn't find a way to compare to other records within the result set like MS Access allows you to do. Then I tried to make a new column in the result set that specifies if a row is unique based on the `t.lp_num` field alone by doing `COUNT(t.lp_num)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT t.lp_num)` but both methods returned a 1. I was hoping that it would return a 2 for the records with `t.lp_num = A` to show that this record has a t.lp_num value repeated twice.

Comment: Count(*) over (partition by t.lp_nm order by t.lp_num desc) ... it will give you count of 2 for A and so on ... based on that you can color your TextBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get the information you need using a window function:

```
select lp_num, lot, qty, count(*) over (partition by lp_num) as Num_lpnum
from t;
```

For your data `Num_lpnum` would be 2 for the "A" rows and 1 for the other rows.

Comment: This is giving me an error: Incorrect syntax near `(` and incorrect syntax near the keyword `GROUP`. What I put in was: `COUNT(*) AS (partition BY t.lp_num) AS Num_lpnum`. The only change I made was to add the prefix `t.` to `lp_num`. I'm not sure what could be causing the `GROUP` error.